# Android Rect Intersect not working

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a collision detection system for a game using Android's Rect class. I'm having a problem where the program is not detecting the intersect on the level floor.

Here's the code to detect intersect in the level class.

```
public void checkVerticalCollision(Rect rbot, Rect rtop){

    if(type != 0){
        if(Rect.intersects(rtop, r)){
            Log.d("CollisionCheck", "Hit Head");
        }

        //System.out.println("Bottom Hitbox" + " " + rbot.top + " " + rbot.bottom + " " + rbot.left + " " + rbot.right);

        if (Rect.intersects(rbot, r)){
            Log.d("CollisionCheck", "Hit Floor");
            player.setJumped(false);
            player.setSpeedY((byte) 0);
            player.setCenterY(tileY - 40);
            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - damage);
        }
    }

}

public void checkSideCollision(Rect rleft, Rect rright){
    if(type != 0 ) {

        if(Rect.intersects(rleft,r)) {
            System.out.println("in left side intersect");
            player.setCenterX(tileX + 88);
            player.setSpeedX((byte) 0);
        }


        if(Rect.intersects(rright,r)) {
            System.out.println("in right side intersect");
            player.setCenterX(tileX + 10);
            player.setSpeedX((byte) 0);
        }   
    }
}
```

The head, left and right hitboxes work. However the bottom hitbox (rbot) does not work (as in intersects never returns true). All the rectangle variables are declared and set in the same way and all update. I've even rendered the hitboxes to check if it is updating with the other rectangles and it is. I am utterly perplexed why this wouldn't work. Please could someone help?

Thanks.

update Rect code in player class:

```
    bottom.set(centerX + 45, centerY + 65, centerX + 20, centerY + 55);
    head.set(centerX + 25 , centerY + 12, centerX + 38, centerY + 4);
    leftHand.set(centerX + 13, centerY + 42, centerX + 23, centerY +  20);
    rightHand.set(centerX + 50, centerY + 42, centerX + 40, centerY + 20);
    check.set(centerX - 40, centerY - 40, centerX + 90, centerY +100);
```

Comment: You said the bottom intersects never returns true. What do values in the debugger say? That's how you'll determine your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the rectangle `bottom` incorrectly. I'm assuming that `bottom` is of type  [`Rect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html), in which case the arguments are to `set` are `set(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`.

For `bottom`, you've set your `left` argument and `right` arguments so that `left` is to the right of `right`.  E.g. if `centerX` is `100`, you'll be setting the left to `145` and the right to `120`, which is the wrong way round.

I think you need to check all your `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` arguments are the right way round as I think there are a couple of other errors too.

Comment: Thanks you! Turns out I inverted the Rectangle!